Calculation of an operator norm $(Tf)(x)=x^2f(x)$
The question is given in the following way:

Let the operator $T:C[0,3]\rightarrow C[0,3]$ be defined by $$(Tf)(x)=x^2f(x), x\in [0,3]$$ If we equip $C[0,3]$ with the norm $\Vert f \Vert_{L^p[0,3]}=(\int_0^3|f(x)|^pdx)^{1/p}$ for $1\leq p < \infty,$ Then calculate the operator norm $\Vert T \Vert.$

In this problem I have already shown $\frac{\Vert (Tf)(x)\Vert_{L^p[0,3]}}{\Vert f\Vert_{L^p[0,3]}}\leq9.$ I cannot find a function with norm $1$ which will attain the value $9$. It was easy to handle if the given interval was $[0,1]$. But what will I do about this problem? Thank you beforehand!!!

Consider the sequence $$f_n(x)=n^{1/p} 1_{[3-1/n, 3]}(x).$$

@SeverinSchraven, I appreciate your answer but will it be continuous over $[0,3]$? How to prove that the limiting function is continuous and has norm 1. Please help me to understand behind thoughts about this example.

I suggest you take the sequence I've suggested and verify that they are normalized in $L^p$, compute $\Vert Tf_n\Vert_p$ and use that to conclude that $\Vert T\Vert \geq 9$. Once you understand that you can think about how one can modify the sequence to make it continuous. It seems you are under the impression that there exists a continuous function $f$ which is normalized in $L^p$ and such that $\Vert Tf\Vert_p=9$. This is not true and also not needed to compute the norm of $T$.

@SeverinSchraven, Thank you very much!!! got the idea...

In general if $Tf=gf$ where $g\in L^\infty,$ the norm is equal $|g|_\infty.$

Let $a, b$ be two points in the interval $J=[0,3]$, $a<b$. Consider the continuous function $f=f_{ab}$ which is piecewise linear, and is $0$ on $[0,a]$, and $1$ on $[b,3]$. We compute $\|Tf\|$ and $\|f\|$ - estimations are enough to obtain lower bounds:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|Tf_{ab}\| &\ge \left(\int_b^3 (x^2\cdot 1)^p\; dx\right)^{1/p}
=\left(\ \frac 1{2p+1}(3^{2p+1}-b^{2p+1})\ \right)^{1/p}\ ,
\\[2mm]
\|f_{ab}\| &\le  \left(\int_a^3 1^p\; dx\right)^{1/p}
=(3-a)^{1/p}\ ,
\\[2mm]
\|T\|
=
\sup_{g\ne 0}\frac{\|Tg\|}{\|g\|}
&\ge
\sup_{0< a < b< 3}\frac{\|Tf_{ab}\|}{\|f_{ab}\|}
\ge
\sup_{0< a < b< 3}\frac{\|Tf_{ab}\|}{\|f_{ab}\|}
\ ,
\\
\|T\|^p
&\ge
\sup_{0< a < b< 3}\frac 1{2p+1}
\cdot \frac{3^{2p+1}-b^{2p+1}}{3-a}
\\
&\ge
\lim_{b\nearrow 3}\lim_{a\nearrow b}\frac 1{2p+1}
\cdot \frac{3^{2p+1}-b^{2p+1}}{3-a}
=
\lim_{b\nearrow 3}
\frac 1{2p+1}
\cdot \frac{3^{2p+1}-b^{2p+1}}{3-b}
\\
&=
\frac\partial{\partial b}
\left(\frac 1{2p+1}
\cdot \frac{3^{2p+1}-b^{2p+1}}{3-b}
\right)_{\text{calculated in }b=3}
=3^{2p}\ ,\text { so}
\\[2mm]
\|T\| &\ge 3^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We already know the opposite estimation, so $\|T\|=3^2$.

Note: The same argument applies for the multiplication operator with a continuous function $h$ on a compact interval. Pick a subinterval where $|h|$ reaches the maximum of length $\epsilon$ enlarge it by a $\delta$, and consider a function which is one on the first interval, and zero on the second interval, completed to be continuous with values between $0$ and $1$ on the remained part of the domain of definition. (For instance taking a piecewise linear function.)

Thank you so much, your answer is very clear and crisp....

As Ryszard Szwarc points out, if $g$ is a bounded function, and $T_g\colon \mathbb L^p\to \mathbb L^p$ (with $p\in [1,\infty)$) is defined by $T_gf=gf$, then $\lVert T_g\rVert=\lVert g\rVert_\infty$. The inequality $\leqslant $ is obvious. For the other, note that for each integer $k$, the set $A_k=\{x: \lvert g(x)\rvert>\lVert g\rVert_\infty-k^{-1}\}$ has positive measure. Let $$
f_k:=\frac 1{\mu(A_k)^{1/p}}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}.$$ One has $\lvert f_k\rvert=\mu(A_k)^{-1/p }\mathbf{1}_{A_k} $ hence $\lVert f_k\rVert_p=1$ and
$$
\int\lvert T_gf_k\rvert^p=\int\left\lvert g\frac 1{\mu(A_k)^{1/p}}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}\right\rvert^p\geqslant \left(\lVert g\rVert_\infty-k^{-1}\right)^p 
$$
hence $\lVert T_g\rVert\geqslant \lVert g\rVert_\infty-k^{-1}$ and since $k$ is arbitrary, the wanted equality follows.
This works for arbitrary $\mathbb L^p$ spaces. If we instead work with the space of continuous on a compact interval $I$ endowed with $\mathbb L^p$-norm (and $g$ continuous), the same idea works. We know that $g$ reaches its supremum at some $x_0$. For each $k$, take a piecewise continuous function $f_k$ taking the value $\left(\lambda(I\cap [x_0-1/k,x_0+1/k])\right)^{-1/p}\lvert g\rvert_\infty$ on $[x_0-1/k,x_0+1/k]\cap I$ and $0$ outside $I\cap [x_0-2/k]$.
